# Using worksheet name as variable

Tags: excel, vba

Please can someone help me out, I seem to be going around in circles with my problem?

I have a workbook with 4 worksheets Comparison, Office1, Office2 and Office3.  On the Comparison sheet the other sheet names are listed in column A.  In column B on this sheet I have a button.

What I want to do is double click the button (I have sorted the code for this) and this will then take you to cell D5 on the corresponding sheet.

At the moment I have the following code but it doesn't seem to activate the Office sheet it uses the comparison sheet.

Could anyone please let me know what I am missing?

Thanks

```
Sub OfficeSht()

Dim rCrit3 As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set rCrit3 = ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-2)
Debug.Print rCrit3
Set ws = rCrit3.Worksheet

ws.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Select

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Application.Goto seems appropriate and reduces the steps to achieve your goal.

```
Sub OfficeSht()
    Dim ws As string

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ws = ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-2).value2
    Debug.Print "'" & ws & "'!D5"
    Application.Goto Reference:="'" & ws & "'!R5C4" '<~~ D5 in xlR1C1


    With Application
        .EnableEvents = true
        .ScreenUpdating = true
    End With

End Sub
```

You may want make this a Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick event.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what kind of button you have so I've give a couple of examples.

One piece of code that is common in all examples is `WorkSheetExists` which checks if the sheet name corresponds to a worksheet.

```
Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String) As Boolean

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

---

Next are three ways to call the `OfficeSht` procedure.

If your buttons are ActiveX button and are in column B you can use:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    OfficeSht Me.Shapes("CommandButton1").TopLeftCell

End Sub
```

This code returns a reference to Top Left Cell that your button sits in - assuming your sheet name is one cell to the left of this.

---

The second way is if you're using a Form button.

```
Public Sub Button_Click()

    OfficeSht Me.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell

End Sub
```

Again, it returns a reference to the Top Left Cell that the button is placed in.  When you add the button just assign it to the `Button_Click` procedure.

---

The third way assumes your button is actually a cell formatted to look like a button, or if you just want to double-click the sheet name in column A and do away with having a button in column B:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    OfficeSht Target

End Sub
```

---

Finally, your code to select cell D5 (Row 5, Column 4 - R5C4).

If you're clicking, or referenced cell is in, column B:

```
Public Sub OfficeSht(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim rDataRange As Range

    Set rLastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    Set rDataRange = Range("A1", rLastCell)

    If Not Intersect(Target, rDataRange.Offset(, 1)) Is Nothing Then
        If WorkSheetExists(Target.Offset(, -1).Value) Then
            Application.Goto "'" & Target.Offset(, -1).Value & "'!R5C4"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

---

If you're clicking, or referenced cell is in, column A:

```
Public Sub OfficeSht(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim rDataRange As Range

    Set rLastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    Set rDataRange = Range("A1", rLastCell)

    If Not Intersect(Target, rDataRange) Is Nothing Then
        If WorkSheetExists(Target.Value) Then
            Application.Goto "'" & Target.Value & "'!R5C4"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Might've waffled on a bit there.... :)

Comment: Thanks for all of this, I have been using the 3rd option, but the info on the others is great and I will remember for the future

Comment: Good stuff.  Feel free to tick as accepted answer if it is.